# Encoding issue Java with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, encoding, character-encoding

I´m doing using XMLHttpRequest to do ajax call to my server.
Suppose my call is:

```
http = new XMLHTTPRequest();
var url = "http://app:8080/search.action?value=ñ"
http.open("GET",url,true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-wwww-form-urlencoded;charset-UTF-8");
http.send(null);
```

In my action I receive in the parameter "value" a question symbol.
I have properly configure tomcat with URIEncoding=UTF-8, also I have a Filter setting the CharacterEncoding to UTF-8 and in web.xml I set the page-encoding to UTF-8.

What I´m missing? why i´m receiving this characters wrong?.

***EDIT:***
This is happening only in IE; in Safari or Firefox, I receive the ñ as expected. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode the parameters in your request.
Try this:

```
var url = "http://app:8080/search.action?value=" + encodeURI('ñ')
```

Comment: Yes, thats works, but I need another solution because the application is very big, i need to do that in more than 1.000 calls.

Comment: EncodingURIComponent is the only way to receive the ñ properly?

Comment: I don't think there is any other way